# Unable to upload app to the iTunes Connect due to Non-public API usage

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect, warnings, wacom

I am trying to upload my App build to iTunes Connect from Xcode 11.3, but getting the below error:

[image]

I am using Wacom WillDevices library in my App. Can someone please give your suggestions?

Comment: I just saw your app's name. 

Comment: Haha.. No prob, I was totally into fixing this bug so forgot to edit :)

Comment: you have any idea?

Comment: Might be one of your library using the same name as used the one of Apple itself. so just needed to rename it.

Comment: Could you check if that method is from really from Wacom WilLDevices Lib? And is in their support there is an issue about that that they need to modify? Are you up to date with their SDK?

Comment: @LarmeI am upto date with SDK. And some of the methods are available in WillDevices Lib.

Comment: Do you have any idea, now I have added WillDevices libraries with 'Do not embed' in Project General page. Earlier I have uploaded the last version of this App with 'Embed & sign', but now when I am selecting this then getting so many errors like "App Store Connect Operation Errors" during App Validation. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This problem will be fixed only when the library you are using updates its method name to not be same as Apple's.

And ofcourse since this is not Apple's own library, you need to "Embed & Sign" it.
Otherwise its unsigned and will fail the validation. Only apples own frameworks which are available on the device do not need to be embedded.